# Hide a website button in my tableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4

This is code for my custom `tableViewCell`

```
 @IBOutlet weak var webButton: UIButton!
 func update(place:EClass) {
        self.place = place
        myLabel.text = place.name
        myImage.image = nil
        myLabel2.text = place.getDescription()

      // IF (didClickWebsite) THE SITE DOESN'T EXIST, MAKE INVISIBLE THE BUTTON webButton


        if let url = place.photos?.first?.getPhotoURL(maxWidth: maxWidht) {
            myImage.af_setImage(withURL: url)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func goToWebSite(_ sender: Any) {

        if let place = place, let delegate = delegate {
                       delegate.didClickWebsite(place: place)

        }
    }
```

where I recently added this button  `@IBOutlet weak var webButton: UIButton!`

and this extension is in the VC of my tableView

```
extension CourseClass2: PlaceCellDelegate {
    func didClickWebsite(place: EClass) {
                NearbyZone.getZoneDetails(place: place) { (place) in
                        if let website = place.details?["website"] as? String, let url = URL(string: website) {
                           let svc = SFSafariViewController.init(url: url)
                           self.navigationController?.pushViewController(svc, animated: true)
                        }
                    }
            }
    }
```

what I would like to do is to tell the `func update` in my custom `tableViewCell` that if the function `didClickWebsite` does not produce any results (in this case when the site does not exist) it has to hide the website button, how caI i do this?

Comment: `webButton.isHidden = true`?

Comment: yes i would like to do that when the func didClickWebsite does not produce any result, how can i do?